# DynamoDB: Possible to use combination of get and write in a single transaction

Tags: amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

I recently started using dynamo DB and was wondering if it's possible to do transactions involving fetching an item and updating another item based on data from first item?
My initial belief is it is not possible with transactional server side api provided by dynamodb but it is possible with client side dynamodb-transactions library provided by awslabs. Any example code for the same in server side api will be much appreciated.

Update: My data model looks like this:

| objectId(Hash Key) | startTime(Sort Key) | endTime | nextStartTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 | 6 | 8 |
| 1 | 8 | 10 | 9 |

So, it's possible a new entry comes in whose start time is 5. So, in transaction I will have to update nextStartTime for second entry to 5 and insert a new entry after the second entry which contains nextStartTime as start time of third entry.
During this another entry might come in which also has start time between second and third entry(say 7 for eg.). Now I want the two transactions to be isolated of each other. In traditional SQL DBs it would be possible as second entry would be locked for the duration of transaction but Dynamo doesn't lock the items. So, I am wondering if I use transaction would the two transactions protect the data integrity.

Comment: That's not possible using the transactions API in DynamoDB.

Comment: @Maurice Have updated the data model. Please have a look if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the use case by changing my data model a little bit to make use of optimistic locking. New data model:

| objectId(Hash Key) | startTime(Sort Key) | endTime | nextStartTime | version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 1 |
| 1 | 8 | 10 | 9 | 1 |

For the first insert for a given hash key, I insert a zero version entry and my entry as a transaction with condition check version attribute not exists. For subsequent inserts for the hash key, I increment the previous entry version with condition check version is same as read(optimistic locking) and insert the new entry as part of a transaction.

Answer (score 4):

The way to solve it with DynamoDB is to use the [conditional expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) in put_item, update_item, or delete_item. The put will fail (similar to the rollback of a transaction) if the condition is not met.

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name SortedList \
    --key '{"objectId": {"N": "1"}, "startTime": {"N": "4"}}' \
    --update-expression "SET nextStartTime = 5" \
    --expression-attribute-values "{"nextStartTime": { "N": "4"}}"
```

With the above `expression-attribute-values` you make sure that the update will fail if the current value is not as you expected, and maybe someone already updated the value in a different thread. In such a failure case, you can read the records again, and try to update with the current value, and so on.

Comment: I have to update/insert a row in table2 using data fetched from table1. How would conditional expression help in that?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I can always go to table1 and modify the value after I updated table2. The conditional update is used if you want to use a value that is already on that record such as the "number of available items" and you don't want to apply a change if someone already changed that record since you read it.

Comment: Have updated. Please have a look.

Comment: DynamoDB is not designed to keep sorted list (which you are trying to implement, if I understand you correctly). Take a look at Redis Sorted Set:https://redis.io/docs/manual/data-types/#sorted-sets

Comment: Nevertheless, I updated the answer to fit your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! I was able to implement my use case by use of conditional expressions and transaction. I added field of version to each entry. For first entry for a given partitionKey and sortKey, I check if version attribute exists in conditional expression and do insert of a zero version entry and my entry as a transaction. For my subsequent entries, I increment the previous entry version and insert the new entry as a transaction.